# What is the difference between NTFS LFS version 2.0 and 1.1?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ntfs

I have two external hard disk drives with the same make/model/capacity WD100EMAZ, and have quick formatted both with a cluster size of 64KB and NTFS.

Oddly, I get a different **LFS Version** on each drive after running `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo <driveletter>`. One is at version 2.0 and the other at 1.1.

Is there a reason for this? Does it affect performance or longevity of the drive?

Answer (score 0):

As of Windows 8.0 (RTM 08/01/2012), the Logical File System was changed in NTFS notably to reduce intensive i/o activity count in logs hence enhancing performance and reducing power use. Whereas one could turn logging off and refrain from multi-boot with other operating systems such as Windows 7 or earlier, they would have needed another computer in order to run the old environment in parallel until feeling comfortable with the newly installed Windows. Hot-plug or removable media was not impacted. On the other hand Windows 8x did not offer a /dax NTFS formatting option, so there was no concern with interoperability on dax volumes.
Also I checked over a year ago that Windows 11 was still using LFS 2.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).